# Existence of weak derivative

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Can a uniformly continuous function have a weak derivative?. In other words can $C_{unif.~cont.}$ be continuously be embedded in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$.?

Comment: It will be great if some one can answer me whether a monotonically increasing (or decreasing) uniformly cont. function has a weak derivative which is bounded?.

Answer (score 3):

Uniformly continuity is not really a very restrictive condition: All continuous functions restricted on $\Omega' \subset \subset \Omega$ is automatically uniform continuous.

To write down a counterexample, consider the [Cantor's staircase function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $f$, which is a monotone function on $(0,1)$ and is uniform continuous. But $f$ is not in $W^{1, 1}(0,1)$ as it does not satisfy the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Thanks a lot John...Can you let me know that under what conditions can a uniformly continuous function become an absolutely continuous function?.

Comment: I do not know any expect the trivial one (for example $f$ is $C^1$). Usually it is the other way round: $W^{1, p}(\Omega)$ can be continuously embedded in $C^{0, \alpha}(\Omega)$ when $p>n$ and $\Omega$ has Lipschitz boundary. @Alexander